# ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing LPX-00651: VM Stack overflow in APEX_JSON.WRITE()

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex-5

I am trying to use new APEX JSON APIs in my code and when I try to generate JSON with large data and nesting, I am getting error as stated in my question. I have tried following code

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
   l_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

  OPEN l_cursor FOR
    SELECT K.KB_ID "KB_ID",
           K.TITLE "TITLE",
           K.CONTENT "CONTENT",
           K.KEYWORDS "KEYWORDS",
           CURSOR(SELECT F.FILE_ID AS "FILE_ID",
                         F.FILE_NAME AS "FILE_NAME",
                         F.FILE_URL AS "FILE_URL"
                  FROM MY_FILES F
                  WHERE F.TYPE_PK = K.KB_ID AND F.TYPE='ITV_KB') AS "Files"
    FROM ITV_KB_ML_V K
    WHERE K.ENABLED = 1;

 APEX_JSON.initialize_clob_output;

 APEX_JSON.open_object;
 APEX_JSON.write('KNOWLEDGE_DATA', l_cursor);
 APEX_JSON.close_object;

 DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(APEX_JSON.get_clob_output);
 APEX_JSON.free_output;
END;
```

I am getting error at `APEX_JSON.write('KNOWLEDGE_DATA',l_cursor)` and my *CONTENT* column has large data, if I comment CONTENT then it works fine. Please suggest what I can use to generate JSON with large data in ORACLE APEX.

Comment: What is size of content column in DB?

Comment: @Prathyush It is of type `CLOB`